# Nextcord (discord.py) slash commands, bot doesn't ping even with admin perms

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

```
    @nextcord.slash_command(name = "chatrevive", description = "pings for chat revive", guild_ids=[ServerId])
@application_checks.has_role(982582539376025640)
@commands.cooldown(1, 7200, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def chatrevive(self, interaction: Interaction, msg: str):
    """Revive the chat!"""

    ping_role = interaction.guild.get_role(855720035426631690)
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title = '<a:tj_mochicat:941582560390160415> Chat Revive', color = 0xff0000)
    embed.set_author(name = interaction.guild.name, icon_url = interaction.guild.icon.url)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=interaction.guild.icon.url)
    embed.description = f"<:tj_greendash:931018157689282581> **Message:** {msg}\n<:tj_greendash:931018157689282581> **Moderator:** {interaction.user.mention}"

    await interaction.send(content = ping_role.mention, embed = embed)
    await post_pinglog(self.bot, interaction.guild, "server-ping", interaction.user, ping_role, "N/A")
```

basically this is working, the only problem is that it mentions the role without pinging it.
[image that shows it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR0bI.png)

*before anyone comments yes I did check the bot's permissions*

Comment: I don't think mentions work in embeds

Comment: this works when using a normal message based command, it just doesn't ping with slash commands weird enough and the fact is that the ping here is outside of the embed as seen in the image

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the allowed mentions for the message, for example, to allow mentioning roles:

```
await interaction.send(
    content=ping_role.mention,
    allowed_mentions=nextcord.AllowedMentions(roles=True),
)
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't fix it, that isn't the issue.
using `interaction.send` simply doesn't ping no matter if you allow mentions or not.
therefore we have to use `interaction.channel.send` instead to bypass this

Comment: @Onlyin1 That's not completely true. I have tested it and it works as described (https://i.imgur.com/91WQ7hS.png). Note, however, If you use defer to extend the interaction, it is actually using a followup webhook instead which does not allow mentions since it is like editing a message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is discord's fault, basically it's impossible to ping using `interaction.send` we'll have to use the following:

```
await interaction.send("Interaction completed.", ephemeral = True)
await interaction.channel.send(f"{ping_role.mention} yadi yadi yada")
```